# Can I run 2 relays in parallel for dry/wet contacts?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, parallel

I have 2 separate relays that are getting 24VAC signals to open/close a NO contact.

The end device (FAN) has 2 terminals that give out 24VAC (SS CMD, wet contact). When SS CMD contacts are jumped/closed, the fan turns on.

Does this diagram work for running them in parallel (if either relay is energized, fan turns on)? If G1/C1 energizes and the contact closes, what will happen to G2/C2 contact since the wires are touching.

Thank you,

[image]

Comment: I'll put in a note to check to make sure that your relays are getting minimum contact current; that signal might be pretty low.

Answer (score 4):

> Does this diagram work for running them in parallel (if either relay is energized, fan turns on)?

Yes. The fan will turn on if either or both switches are turned on. You have an 'OR' configuration.

```
G1  G2  Fan
 0   0    0
 1   0    1
 0   1    1
 1   1    1
```

> If G1/C1 energizes and the contact closes, what will happen to G2/C2 contact since the wires are touching.

Since the wires are connected by the first switch to close they will now have 0 V between them. The second contact (which is still open) has 0 V across it. Nothing will happen.